# Automatically continue shopping when product is added to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I'm using the default 1.9 theme and I want customers to automatically continue shopping when they add a product to the cart.

The default setting is that once a product is added to the cart, they get redirected to the shopping cart and have two major options, either "Continue shopping" or "Proceed to checkout".

How do I make sure the customer only get's redirected to the shopping cart when they want so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It's just a configuration setting. System -> Configuration -> Sales tab -> Checkout and then in the Shopping Cart tab you set the After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart to No. Easy! Good luck with the Big M :) "

Source here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042318/magento-how-can-i-prevent-to-go-immediately-to-the-shopping-cart-page-once-i-h